# Can you share a gulp framework between projects?

Tags: node.js, frameworks, gulp, shared-libraries, shared

I have many projects that all follow specific folder structures and conventions.

Rather than duplicating the whole project, I'd like to just have a configuration object for each project and each project links to the global framework.

Example:

```
/gulp-framework
    index.js
/project-a
    gulpfile.js
    configuration.js
/project-b
    gulpfile.js
    configuration.js
```

Inside index.js

```
var configuration = require('configuration');
```

Inside configuration.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
   return { foo : true };
}
```

Inside the gulp file I would have:

```
require('./configuration');
require('../gulp-framework');
```

However running gulp just leaves me with an error

'Cannot find module configuration'.

I guess all I'm trying to do is pass in a config object to the global framework but not having much luck.

Ideas?

Comment: I think you forget "./" var configuration = require('./configuration'); inside index.js

Comment: No I'm trying to reference the exported module from configuration.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically using `require('configuration')` in `index.js` will look for the `configuration` module in `/gulp-framework/node_modules/`. It will not load the `configuration.js` from `project-a` or `project-b`. (Read more on the exact logic of how `require()` works [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).)

You need to explicitly pass the configuration and gulp object from your `gulpfile.js` to `index.js`:

In each **gulpfile.js**:

```
var config = require('./configuration.js');
var gulp = require('../gulp-framework')(require('gulp'), config);

// project-specific stuff using gulp and config goes here
```

In **index.js**:

```
module.exports = function(gulp, config) {
  // project-independent stuff using gulp and config goes here

  return gulp;
};
```

Comment: Awesome I'll try this tomorrow and read up on require! Cheers

Comment: This worked great to solve this problem, I guess the last problem is, seeing how my main framework lives under /gulp-framework

Is it possible to have the gulpfile.js inside each project, use the global node_modules folder? It seems to still be looking for the node_modules inside project-a/node_modules

Comment: Two options: 1. [Loading from global folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders). 2. Make `project-a` a subdir of `gulp-framework`.